# RStudio Server Unable To Connect To Service

Tags: r, rstudio-server

When I attempt to login to the server, I get through the username and password screen just fine (it rejects bad username/password combinations, and accepts the correct one). However, once I enter my username and password, it stalls for a moment with a message that reads Unable to connect to service.

Error log is:

```
Sep 24 12:22:41 ABRILPREDSVR1 kernel: [1495156.302209] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Sep 24 12:22:50 ABRILPREDSVR1 rserver[21509]: ERROR system error 2 (No such file or directory) [child-path=/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rsession]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::system::launchChildProcess(std::string, std::string, rstudio::core::system::ProcessConfig, rstudio::core::system::ProcessConfigFilter, PidType*) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/system/PosixSystem.cpp:1433; LOGGED FROM: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::system::launchChildProcess(std::string, std::string, rstudio::core::system::ProcessConfig, rstudio::core::system::ProcessConfigFilter, PidType*) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/system/PosixSystem.cpp:1435
```

I have accidentally deleted rsession file . What to do now

Also when I am running `sudo rstudio-server verify-installation` Its returning error.

```
 24 Sep 2019 11:03:10 [rserver] ERROR system error 2 (No such file or directory) [child-path=/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rsession]; 
OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::system::launchChildProcess(std::string, std::string, rstudio::core::system::ProcessConfig, rstudio::core::system::ProcessConfigFilter, PidType*) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/system/PosixSystem.cpp:1433; 
LOGGED FROM: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::system::launchChildProcess(std::string, std::string, rstudio::core::system::ProcessConfig, rstudio::core::system::ProcessConfigFilter, PidType*) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/system/PosixSystem.cpp:1435
```

Also while running this `sudo rstudio-server status` I am getting this

```
Sep 24 16:59:26 ABRILPREDSVR1 systemd[1]: Failed to start RStudio Server.
Sep 24 16:59:26 ABRILPREDSVR1 systemd[1]: Stopped RStudio Server.
Sep 24 16:59:26 ABRILPREDSVR1 systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 24 16:59:26 ABRILPREDSVR1 systemd[1]: Failed to start RStudio Server.
Sep 24 16:59:26 ABRILPREDSVR1 systemd[1]: Stopped RStudio Server.
Sep 24 16:59:26 ABRILPREDSVR1 systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 24 16:59:26 ABRILPREDSVR1 systemd[1]: Failed to start RStudio Server.
Sep 24 16:59:26 ABRILPREDSVR1 systemd[1]: Stopped RStudio Server.
Sep 24 16:59:26 ABRILPREDSVR1 systemd[1]: rstudio-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 24 16:59:26 ABRILPREDSVR1 systemd[1]: Failed to start RStudio Server.
```

Rstudio server was working yesterday ,after that i deleted rsession file on /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/ accidentally , and I tried loading rstudio server on browser today and it gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled R and other related components form ubuntu 16.04 server and then reinstalled again.